# ng serve doesn't work on Windows10 (angular-cli, node 6.3.0)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-cli

Following simplest tutorial on https://cli.angular.io/

```
ng new my-app
cd my-app
ng serve
```

I receive following error

```
(node:5888) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. 
If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve command.
```

The message "*You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the serve command.*" is written in red, so it's not a warning

Node, npm, and graceful-fs are the latest version at the moment.

```
>ng version
(node:7288) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.9
node: 6.3.0
os: win32 x64
```

Any ideas besides doing this on mac/linux?

**Update:** 
solution is to install [NVM](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases) and install node.js version 5.12.0 (or any 5.x)

```
nvm install 5.12.0
nvm use 5.12.0
npm install -g angular-cli
npm install -g typescript
```

After re-doing tutorial everything works just great.

Comment: can you please show me what `ng version` gives you in the terminal

Comment: @pdfarhad sure, here you are!

Comment: isnt that just a warning?

Comment: first one is warning, second one (you have to be ..) is error and serve is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

node v6 is still not supported in many packages. Consider going back to v5.